# Why am I unable to add an existing data into a new dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset containing 250 employee names, gender and their salary. I am trying to create a new dataframe to simply 'extract' the salary for males and females respectively. This dataframe would have 2 columns, one with Male Salaries and another with Female Salaries.

From this dataframe, I would like to create a side by side boxplot with matplotlib to analyse if there is any gender wage gap.

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TMA_Data.csv")
df.head()

#Filter out female employees
df_female = df[(df.Gender == "F")]
df_female.head()

#Filter out male employees
df_male = df[(df.Gender == "M ")]
df_male.head()

#Create new dataframe with only salaries
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Male Salaries", "Female Salaries"])
print(df2)

#Assign Male Salaries column
df2["Male Salaries"] = df_male["Salary"]
df2.head() #This works

Output: 
    Male Salaries   Female Salaries
3   93046   NaN
7   66808   NaN
10  46998   NaN
16  74312   NaN
17  50178   NaN

#Assign Female Salaries column (THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES)
df2["Female Salaries"] = df_female["Salary"]
df2.head()
```

Output:

```
Male Salaries   Female Salaries
3   93046   NaN
7   66808   NaN
10  46998   NaN
16  74312   NaN
17  50178   NaN
```

How come I am unable to add the values for female salaries (nothing seems to be added)? Also, given that my eventual goal is to create two side-by-side boxplots, feel free to suggest if I can do this in a completely different way. Thank you very much!

Edit: Dataset preview:

[image: Dataset contents]

Comment: Could you share a piece of your data ? I think the problem is there

Comment: Are both series the same length?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you increase your chances of receiving a useful answer!

Comment: Both series are of different lengths. There are more female employees than male. I have shared the data preview image in the edit above, thanks!

Comment: You don’t need to (and can’t) have different length data series as columns. Just do `df.plot.box("salary", by="gender")`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

Use [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Male Salaries", "Female Salaries"])
df2["Male Salaries"] = df_male["Salary"].reset_index(drop=True)
df2["Female Salaries"] = df_female["Salary"].reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Explanation:

When setting values of a column of the dataframe, they are set to their respective indices.

And your `Male` and `Female` indices are obviously different, since they came from different rows of the initial dataframe.

#### Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3]])
df
```

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Works as you expected:

```py
df[1] = [4, 5, 6]
df
```

```
    0   1
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Works NOT as you expected:

```py
df[2] = pd.Series([4, 5, 6], index=[1, 0, 999])
df
```

```
    0   1   2
0   1   4   5.0
1   2   5   4.0
2   3   6   NaN
```